app crash when pick file in huawei phone - Flutter
I programmed an application using Flutter and added packages for uploading files as shown below, and the application works correctly on other phones except Huawei phones, where when uploading files the app crash I see the problem below
Flutter HWUI Binary is  disabled 
  image_cropper: ^5.0.1
  image_picker: ^1.0.4 


  pickImageFromGallery() async {
    final selectedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (selectedFile != null) {
      CroppedFile? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
        sourcePath: selectedFile.path,
        aspectRatioPresets: [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
          CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
        ],
        uiSettings: [
          AndroidUiSettings(
              toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
              toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
              initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
              lockAspectRatio: false),
          IOSUiSettings(
            title: 'Cropper',
          ),
          WebUiSettings(
            context: context,
          ),
        ],
      );

      if (croppedFile != null) {
        setState(() {
          imagePath = croppedFile.path;
        });
      }
    }
  }


Flutter HWUI Binary is  disabled

Is this file uploaded to Firebase or Firestore?

Yes, but the problem occurs when selecting the file
Widget Form with steps
The first step is to fill out the information
The second step is to download the file
The Three Step  Contact Information
